# Is there a way to add badge notifications using progressive web apps (PWA)?

Tags: android, google-chrome, notifications, progressive-web-apps, badge

I'm developing a progressive web application (PWA) that will eventually send notifications to users.

I already know I'm able to send push notifications (like any regular app), as explained in the following blog post: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=en-us.

I also know that I can add a PWA to the home screen, by creating a simple manifest file (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android).

However, after having the app in home screen, I would like to add a "hint" to users, letting they know that they have to access the application. A great way to do that is doing something like a "badge notification" (as showed in Facebook icon on the image below).

[image: Image showing a badge notification example on the Facebook icon]

Is it possible to add this kind of behavior using progressive web applications?

---

#### Update - December, 15th, 2018

Google recently launched a post explaining about the so called "Badging for App Icons", which is pretty exciting:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/badging-api

#### Update - September, 28th, 2018

Relevant Links:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719176&desc=2
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=685159
- https://github.com/mgiuca/badging/blob/master/explainer.md
- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AmX53h-gk8wN7LPMi_Mq7fsIMgsMKRD6zKa1Ymxxvvc/edit#

As Josh Lee pointed out in [Is there a way to add badge notifications using progressive web apps (PWA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377604/is-there-a-way-to-add-badge-notifications-using-progressive-web-apps-pwa#comment92060867_45377604), there are some discussions about the subject on the chromium team.

Looking at the [discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719176&desc=2#c29):

> FYI, the notification indicators are being pushed to M-71.

and

> Thanks for the heads up. That's fine for us because while we hope to have this testable behind a flag in M70, there's no way we'll be launching the API before (at least) M71.

So, maybe, at least for now, it seems that it's not possible to add badge notifications for PWAs, but maybe in the future we'll be able to do that.

Comment: Is this still the case? Would love to have this option!

Comment: @karns, yes, but, unfortunately, I still haven't found a way to do that! :(

Comment: @WilliamMartins where you able to figure this out yet? Having the same issue.

Comment: @Wonka still haven't figured it out yet. :/ I gave up a few months ago to investigate this, due to lack of information about it

Comment: I know this is a very useful feature to have but we need some more answers. I just started a bounty on it, hopefully we get a concrete answer :)

Comment: https://crbug.com/719176 https://crbug.com/685159

Comment: Hey @Wonka, I updated the question with some links provided by Josh Lee. I read the discussion in chromium forum and it looks like they will implement that in the future, however, I think that currently we can't do that. If Josh Lee wants to answer the question with that, I can happily accept the answer

Comment: @WilliamMartins Yup, I read the discussion too posted by Josh Lee looks like they have a spec in place based on the GitHub link explainer and are working on implementing it. One thing I don't get is how do we know the current "M" version at the moment, since they mentioned "M71" Any idea?

Comment: @Wonka, no clue, maybe this is their release names, as Chrome is currently in 69.x.y

Comment: @WilliamMartins yup, just found this which lists their releases https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/

Comment: @JoshLee Do you mind sharing your comment as an answer for the bounty?

Comment: @Wonka Oh sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2020:** [check this nikhil mehta's answer below for the latest information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62960692/3163075):

> The App Badging API works on Windows, and macOS, in Chrome 81 or later. It has also been confirmed to work on Edge 84 or later. Support for Chrome OS is in development and will be available in a future release of Chrome. On Android, the Badging API is not supported. Instead, Android automatically shows a badge on app icon for the installed web app when there is an unread notification, just as for Android apps.

**Original answer:**

Looks like this is on the roadmap, possibly behind a flag in M71.

- [crbug.com/719176](https://crbug.com/719176)
- [crbug.com/685159](https://crbug.com/685159)

(So, a late October beta ([schedule](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/schedule)). There's no other activity on the bug to corroborate that, but most of the WebAPK work was not on public bugs, FWIW.)

Answer (score 5):

Just in case some one comes looking for answer here

It is supported now in chrome and chromium based browsers.
Here are the imp Links to know more

- [W3C Badging API Explainer](https://github.com/w3c/badging/blob/main/explainer.md)
- [Demo App](https://badging-api.glitch.me/) (installable PWA)
- [Demo App Source Code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/badging-api?path=demo.js%3A1%3A0)
- [Web.dev in short know how](https://web.dev/badging-api/)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/badging-api) it is a work in progress and available as an origin trial or through the flag `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` on Chrome 73 and there is also a [demo](https://badging-api.glitch.me/) for Windows and MacOS.

Regarding other platforms:

> Android is not supported because it requires you to show a notification, though this may change in the future.

While there is no information available regarding Safari or OSX.

Comment: Still the state :(

Comment: Still only available as an origin trial, but it seems that launch will happen soon as there has been progress on the documentation and API.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to do this with PWAs. Although if developers like the feature I expect it will at some point.

Comment: are you sure sir ?