# How to show count on "PWA web application icon" through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

How to show count on "PWA web application icon" through JavaScript?

I have implemented FCM push notification already in system but does not know how to show count for launcher icon in PWA web app

Answer (score 1):

Currently badge's notifications are not possible in PWA's but they'll be available in the future. Google has already an experimental API for it.
You can get further info in [Is there a way to add badge notifications using progressive web apps (PWA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377604/is-there-a-way-to-add-badge-notifications-using-progressive-web-apps-pwa)